# Считывать скролл только с определённого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Надо чтобы скролл считывался именно в блоке "second", а не с начала документа и, когда в конце концов посты через ajax будут подгружены, то переходило спокойно на третий блок. Короче говоря надо, чтобы действия происходили только в блоке "second".

```
<div class="first"></div> 
<div class="second">
    <div class="post"></div> 
</div>
<div class="third"></div>




 jQuery(window).on('scroll', onScroll); 
    function onScroll(){ 
      if (jQuery(window).scrollTop() +    100   + jQuery(window).height()   > jQuery(document).height()) {
      //ajax
      }
    }
```

Comment: вместо `jQuery(window)` используй `jQuery("#ID_блока")`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov попробовал, но что то не пошло

Comment: странно, написал тест ниже, вроде как раз отрабатывает на скролл в одном из  div

Comment: @AndreyMaslov написал вам в комментарии свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="first" style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:#00ff00;overflow:scroll;">
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
</div> 

<div class="second" style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:#ff0000;overflow:scroll;">
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
</div>

<div class="third" style="width:100px; height:100px;background-color:#0000ff;overflow:scroll;">
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
1111111111111111111111111111<br>
</div>



<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH_TO_JQUERY"></script>
<script language="Javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".third").on('scroll', onScroll); 
    function onScroll(evt){ 
      console.log("scroll", evt);
  }
});    
</script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: ну вот я так поставил , что то у меня не подгружаются посты при скролле. Работает всё только с моим вариантом. Я поставил alert в функции , но что то не срабатывает

Comment: ну хз, по консоли видно, что он пишет сообщение когда идет скролинг в нужном div

Comment: Очень странно...

Comment: Смотри проблема, наверное, в том, что когда в блоке нет данных он не может в принципе принимать событие scroll, добавь туда пустых строк, что бы скролл в принципе мог отрабатываться

Comment: у меня там данных очень много :D у меня маркап чуть другой :) просо в вопрос такой маркап не написать , так как его смотреть никто не будет , поэтому я сделал очень упрощённую версию  :)

Comment: я в своем коде, попробовал убрать содержимое у div, который нужно скроллировать, в итоге сообщения о скролле пропали

Comment: а если в этот див (second) вставить 4 внутренних блока и только в последним будет инфа, то шпарить будет ?

Comment: Просто у меня он не читает эту строчку jQuery('.second').on('scroll', onScroll); Потому что , если стоит window то всё работает, а если заменять на класс или id , то не работает